# How to access a elements of a struct of type array

Tags: rust

I created the following struct

```
pub const BUCKET_SIZE: usize = 4;

pub const FINGERPRINT_SIZE: usize = 1;

pub struct Fingerprint ([u8; FINGERPRINT_SIZE]);

impl Fingerprint {
    pub fn new(bytes: [u8; FINGERPRINT_SIZE]) -> Fingerprint {
        return Fingerprint(bytes);
    }
}

pub struct Bucket ([Fingerprint; BUCKET_SIZE]);

impl Bucket {
    pub fn new(fingerprints: [Fingerprint; BUCKET_SIZE]) -> Bucket {
        Bucket(fingerprints)
    }
    pub fn insert(&self, fp: Fingerprint) -> bool {
        for i in 0..BUCKET_SIZE {



            //HERE IS THE ERROR
            if (self[i as usize] == 0) {
                self[i as usize] = fp;
                return true;
            }



        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When trying to compile it i get the following error

```
error: cannot index a value of type `&bucket::Bucket`
```

Does it make more sense to make Buckets hold a property fingerprints instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type `Bucket` is a tuple struct with one field, which you can access with `.0`.

So you can change the code to:

```
        if (self.0[i as usize] == 0) {
            self.0[i as usize] = fp;
            return true;
        }
```

You will also need to change the function argument from `&self` to `&mut self` so that you can mutate the fields of `self`.

Comment: Sweet thanks. Worked. Looking at a new error though.  self.0[i as usize] == 0      >>>>> error: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `bucket::Fingerprint` [E0369]

Comment: Fingerprint is also a tuple struct, so you need it needs to be `self.0[i as usize].0 == 0`. Also, you could look into implementing the Index trait to make indexing into these tuple structs directly.